# Databinding to the value of a multiBinding

Tags: wpf, xaml, multibinding

Maybe I am not quite grasping multibindings.

I have a property on my viewmodel called OfficeDisplayName that is written to the database.

This is a concatenated field based on a person's FirstName, Lastname, and office location.

So I have a multibinding on a textBlock...no biggie...works beautifully...but how do I bind the full value of this concatenation to the OfficeDisplayName property? Do I have to have a hidden element that binds to the multibound textbox? I have seen several examples that are almost what I need, but just dont answer the concat databinding question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to let the textblock bind directly to `OfficeDisplayName` and then put the concatenation logic in the `OfficeDisplayName` property on your viewmodel instead of in the `MultiValueConverter`.  So when ever one of the properties FirstName, LastName, or office location change you'd fire the `PropertyChanged` event for `OfficeDisplayName` - i.e. something along the following lines.  This way you will not need a converter at all:

```
class YourViewModel : ViewModel
{
    string _firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (_firstName != value)
            {
                _firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                OnPropertyChanged("OfficeDisplayName");
            }
        }
    }

    // More properties here
    // ...

    public string OfficeDisplayName
    {
        get { return String.Join(" ", new string[] { _firstName, _lastName, _officeLocation}); }
    }
}
```

Another way is to pass your viewmodel itself as a parameter to your `MultiValueConverter`.  In your converter you can set the value of `OfficeDisplayName` directly.  I think this way is a bit "hack-ish" but it is a matter of taste.  Your code would look like the following:

The binding in XAML:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource theConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
    <Binding /> <!-- Pass the datacontext as the first parameter -->
    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
    <Binding Path="LastName" />
</MultiBinding>
```

The converter:

```
class TheMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var viewModel = values[0] as TheViewModel;
        var ret = String.Join(" ", values.Skip(1).Cast<string>().ToArray());
        viewModel.OfficeDisplayName = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Ok...this really got me started so I voted you up. However...hehe...I need to save this value to the database but at the same time make sure I am reading an accurate value from the database...so I have to do something in the setter....I am guessing in the long run I may have to pass the viewmodel.

Comment: +1 for this - <Binding /> <!-- Pass the datacontext as the first parameter -->